# Non-invocable member 'List<PKT, T>.FilterFunction' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#

I have an error when tried using `FilterFunction` like method.

When an error occurs, I do not know how to resolve it?

I'm only using code like:

I created function delegate like:

```
internal class FilterFunctionDelegate<PKT, T>
{
}
```

Then, in class `FDBindingList!2.cs`, I set this class:

```
private FilterFunctionDelegate<PKT, T> FilterFunction;

internal delegate bool FilterFunctionDelegate(T item);

internal void Add(T item)
{
    if ((this.FilterFunction == null) || this.FilterFunction(item)){}
}
```

In `ArbsBindingList.cs`:

```
base.SetFilter(new FDBindingList<long, Arb>.FilterFunctionDelegate(this.Filter.IsSatisfies));
```

My error is:

At line `this.FilterFunction(item)`:

> Non-invocable member 'FDBindingList.FilterFunction' cannot be used like a method

And line:

> Cannot convert from 'JustXin.Windows.Forms.FDBindingList.FilterFunctionDelegate' to 'JustXin.Windows.Forms.FilterFunctionDelegate'

Comment: In your case `FilterFunctionDelegate` is both, a class-name and the name of the delegate. This is weird and should cause the error as compiler is not able to distinguish them. Use another name for the class.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Can you add more code to the answer? I was add `FilterFunctionDelegate+Class` and it change to: `internal class FilterFunctionDelegateClass<PKT, T>` and `private FilterFunctionDelegateClass<PKT, T> FilterFunction;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FilterFunctionDelegate` is both, a class-name and the name of the delegate. This is weird and should cause the error as compiler is not able to distinguish them. However I dounbt you need the class in any way, just go with the delegate within `FDBindingList!2.cs` (weird file-name btw., the `!` might cause problems):

```
internal delegate bool FilterFunctionDelegate(T item);

internal void Add(T item)
{
    if ((this.FilterFunctionDelegate == null) || this.FilterFunctionDelegate(item)) { /* ... */ }
}
```

To assign the delegate simply write something similar to this:

```
fdbFindingList.FilterFunctionDelegate = delegate(T item) { /* your delegate function here*/ }
```

The same could also be achieved by using the more .NET-3.5-like `Func<T>`:

```
internal Func<T, bool> FilterFunctionDelegate;

// ...
```

Now set it like this

```
fdbFindingList.FilterFunctionDelegate = (T) => /* your delegate-code here*/
```

And call it like this:

```
var list = new FDBindingList<long, Arb>();
list.FilterFunctionDelegate = ...
list.FilterFunctionDelegate(MyInstanceOfT)
```

Comment: Hey @himbrombeere, I tried change this line: `if ((this.FilterFunctionDelegate == null) || this.FilterFunctionDelegate(item)) { /* ... */ }` it also show error like this: `FDBindingList<PKT, T>.FilterFunctionDelegate' is a type, which is not valid in the given context` and `on-invocable member 'FDBindingList<PKT, T>.FilterFunctionDelegate' cannot be used like a method.`.

Comment: Maybe you can try  the `Func`-approach?